# PHP Store Variables across multiple form submissions

Tags: php, html, forms

EDIT: Question had a simple answer: the $_SESSION variable. Thanks to RiggsFolly for that.

Suppose I would like to save the users data to a variable that they would later be able to access for one reason or another, and I need the value in that variable to be persistent across form submissions and page refreshes.

What is the 'best' (in this case the most efficient) way to do this in PHP?

Here's a code sample illustrating the issue: It consists of three buttons for submitting data, saving data, and loading data. It does not work, but merely conveys the idea.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<? 

    /* If Save Pressed --> Stored the value in a variable that will persist across successive submissions/refreshes*/
    if(isset($_GET['save'])){
        $_GET['saved'] = $_GET['value'];
    }

    /* If Submit Pressed -> Display the value entered in the text box next to Value:*/
    if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
        $loadedValue = $_GET['value'];
    }

    /* If Load Pressed -> Loads the previously stored value if there is one and displays it next to Value: */
    if(isset($_GET['load'])){
        $loadedValue = $_GET['saved'];
    }
?>
<form>
<!--  New Value Entry Field -->
<input type="text" name="value" >

<!-- Space Characters -->
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;          

<!-- Original Value Text -->
<u>Value:</u> <?= $loadedValue ?>   

<!-- Line Break Characters -->
<br><br>
<!-- Button To Change Values -->
<input type="submit" name="submit"value="Submit">   

<!-- Button To Save Values -->
<input type="submit" name="save"value="Save">   

<!-- Button To Load Values -->
<input type="submit" name="load"value="Load">   
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: You need to read up on SESSION [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Comment: This is all I needed to do. Thank you, editing the question now.

Comment: Rather than editing the question, please either: 1) Post an answer yourself and accept it, if you believe this post may be helpful to future SO users, or 2) Delete your question.

Comment: ^^^ Will do next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like duatis said just include on the top of the page before anything

```
<?php session_start() ; ?>
```

And then assign the variable u want to store it for all pages using the following

```
$_SESSION['variablename'] = $your variable ;
```

And when you want to call this variable from another page you have to include also at the top of the page:

```
<?php session_start() ; ?>
```

And then you just use the variable as

```
$_SESSION['variablename']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use session variables.
[PHP: $_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

I don't know if you are familiar with sessions but basically is a system that identifies your current conection with the server so information can be persisted during that session.